# How to rotate an object with single finger touch gesture in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing an application on Unity for Android Mobile platform. In which I am rotating object with single finger touch gesture, with the help of this script,

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseDragRotate : MonoBehaviour {
    float rotationSpeed = 0.02f;

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
         float XaxisRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*rotationSpeed;
         float YaxisRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")*rotationSpeed;
         // select the axis by which you want to rotate the GameObject
         transform.RotateAround (Vector3.down, XaxisRotation);
         transform.RotateAround (Vector3.right, YaxisRotation);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that, this script is working only on all Unity Assets for example cube, sphere, capsule and others. But not working with third party 3d objects,

So simply the question is why this script is not working on third party 3d objects ?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by third party objects? Do you mean assets from the asset store, or meshes downloaded from the web and imported into Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have some sort of a `Collider` attached to the 3d-model/Object you would like to interact with. What you can do is add a `BoxCollider` to any Imported Object, or if there is a `MeshFilter` attached you could also add a `MeshCollider`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the script you show is added to the right top level object and not in a nested component of that object.
If you are still having problems please show us more about the objects you are trying to apply this to. And what components and option are set to it.

Comment: I am just curious, I just find out that `collider` is not attached with third party objets. Is `collider` is necessary for touch gestures ?

Comment: @HeisenBrg a collider is necessary for touch gestures so that the collision can be recognized. As far as I know it is implemented with a ray cast, even if it is hidden behind the touch API.